# Why is a folder not deleted with RMDIR in batch file as last command?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
xcopy /Y /S %CD%\Code\Release C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt /I
cls
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt\
call "Trabalho AEDA.exe"
xcopy /Y /S C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt\FICHEIROS\ %CD%\Code\Release\FICHEIROS\
RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt
```

That copies a folder to a location, runs the .exe from it and then it overwrites the original files in my folder and has do delete the ones initially copied.

The folder I copy to the user desktop has other folder inside, and the .exe.
At the final line of the .bat, it deletes everything in the folder, but the folder is kept in the `Desktop` folder. I want to delete it, too. I tried several instructions, but without success.

**EDIT:** That was the issue, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with deleting `ShareIt` folder is already answered by the other answers.

It is not possible on Windows to delete a folder which is the current working directory of any running process or in which a file is opened by an application with a file lock preventing the deletion of the opened file.

In this case the `ShareIt` folder is the current working directory of the command process executing the batch file because the batch file explicitly sets this directory as working directory. The solution is making any other directory the working directory for the command process.

But this is not the only potential problem of the few command lines of this batch file. There are some more.

`%CD%` could expand to a path which contains perhaps one or more spaces or other characters like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which require enclosing complete folder path in double quotes. This list of characters is output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` in last paragraph on last output help page.

Also `%CD%` expands to a folder path usually not ending with a backslash, except the current directory is the root directory of a drive. So `%CD%\Code\Release` could for example expand to `C:\\Code\Release` with two backslashes in path. However, this is no real problem as Windows kernel corrects the path automatically on whatever file system access function is used internally by `xcopy` for copying the files and folders.

Parameter `/I` lets `xcopy` interpret the target string as folder path even if folder path is not ending with a backslash, but only if multiple files are copied like when source path is a folder path like it is here obviously the case. Otherwise on copying just a single file `/I` is ignored by `xcopy`. Best for a folder path as target is specifying the target folder path with a backslash as then `xcopy` interprets target always as folder path. It is easier to use here paths relative to current directory and omit `%CD%` completely.

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%` is not good as the user's profile directory can be also on a different drive than `C:` and can be in a different directory than `Users`, for example on Windows XP. The path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` is the default for the user's profile directory since Windows Vista. But every user has the freedom to change it also on Windows Vista and later Windows versions. There is the environment variable `USERPROFILE` defined by Windows which contains full path to active user's profile directory. See Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for more details about predefined Windows environment variables.

And of course the user's profile directory path could contain one or more spaces or other characters which again require double quotes around complete folder path or file name, for example if the user account name contains a space character. So again double quotes should be used wherever `%USERPROFILE%` or `%USERNAME%` is used in a folder or file name with path.

Command **CD** without parameter `/D` changes the current directory only on current drive if the new current directory exists at all on current drive. So with current directory on starting the batch file being on a different drive than drive `C:`, changing the current directory with used code would not work at all.

The command **CALL** should not be necessary at all in case of `Trabalho AEDA.exe` is really an executable as the file extension indicates. **CALL** can be used also for an executable, but it is designed primary for running a subroutine or calling another batch file from within a batch file.

The last two lines do not really make sense because the current directory was changed by the batch file to `ShareIt` folder in desktop folder of current user. Therefore `%CD%\Code\Release\FICHEIROS\` expands to

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt\Code\Release\FICHEIROS\
```

as target path for `xcopy` and the last line deletes the entire folder

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt
```

That is obviously not the intention. `xcopy` in last but one line should copy the files to a subdirectory in initial current directory.

I suggest to use this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe Code\Release "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt\" /C /Q /R /S /Y >nul
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt"
if not errorlevel 1 "Trabalho AEDA.exe" & popd
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt\FICHEIROS" Code\Release\FICHEIROS\ /C /Q /R /S /Y >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!CD:%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt=!" == "!CD!" RMDIR /S /Q "!USERPROFILE!\Desktop\ShareIt"
endlocal
endlocal
```

The last **IF** conditions needs most likely an additional explanation for what is its purpose.

`!CD:%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt=!` results in searching case-insensitive in current directory path string for all occurrences of the path string to `ShareIt` directory in desktop directory of current user and replacing all found occurrences by an empty string. So it depends on what is the current directory on what happens here.

In case of current directory is `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt`, the string left of comparison operator `==` becomes `""`. In case of current directory is a subdirectory of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ShareIt`, the string left of `==` becomes a relative path to this directory enclosed in double quotes. In all other cases the string left of `==` is not modified at all and expands to path of current directory enclosed in double quotes like the string right of the comparison operator.

So the **IF** condition checks if the current directory is NOT the `ShareIt` directory or a subdirectory of this directory in the desktop directory of current user. Only in this case it is safe to delete the entire `ShareIt` directory.

**Note:** The **IF** condition does not work correct on `%USERPRFOLE%` expands to a folder path string containing one or more `!` because of enabled delayed variable expansion.

For understanding all other used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

There should be read also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot. I was also getting trouble running it in other machines, but that all solved it! Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

`ShareIt` folder isn't deleted probably because you are in the folder.
So, adding `cd ..` before `RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt` solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you execute

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ShareIt\
```

It's the current directory when you execute the `now delete the directory` command.

Move to another directory, and then try the deletion